# How to get the IP address of a connected WebSocket-client?

Tags: websocket, abap

I'm currently working on a ABAP Push Channel server to WebSocket client connection and I need the IP-address of the client in order to identify whether this client is the one I want to send the message to. In my scenario there could be multiple WebSocket connections.

Now there is the `ssi_websocket_table` table and the `ssi_websocket_table_row` row with the the field `caller_ip`, however this gives me the IP address of the DNS-Server of the network I'm connected to, and I expected the IP address of my local PC since the WebSocket-client is running on this machine.

Is there any other way to get the clients IP address from an active WebSocket connection in ABAP?

P.S. Looking at all the table entries, it shows the correct IP when using a different server configuration, as soon as I know why that's the case I will report back.

Comment: Identifying clients by IP address is a jolly bad idea IMHO. Not guaranteed to be stable or unique, easily spoofed.

Comment: these are websocket connections, the clients start the connection and do the authentication first, so any active websocket connection is a valid secure client server connection, but i still need to know which ip belongs to which device-id to i can send messages back to the one its intended for

Comment: What happens if you've got two devices with 192.168.42.42 NATed in from different networks via the same gateway? How are you going to tell them apart?

Comment: you are right, it makes no sense then to use the IP at all. I will opt for a websocket ID and device ID instead.

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy I put your solution from the question into separate answer so that people can find it

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by vwegert it makes no sense to use the IP to tell the WebSockets apart, I think it would probably be better to use an ID for each WebSocket connection instead.

You could get the IP from the WebSocket server context which gets the IP header apparently from the opening HTTP handshake for the connection:

```
DATA(lo_context) = i_context. " IF_APC_WSP_SERVER_CONTEXT type
DATA(lo_request) = lo_context->get_initial_request( ).

" initialize G_CONTEXT_ID_FIELD for PCP_SET_CONTEXT_FIELDS
DATA(lv_id) = lo_request->get_header_field( if_http_header_fields_sap=>remote_addr ).
```

the sample is taken from the SAP standard class `CL_APC_WS_EXT_ABAP_ONLINE_COMM`, `ON_MESSAGE` method.